# Print differences in CSV files by comparing values in column (using awk)

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Say I have 2 files - `file1.csv` and `file2.csv`. I need to compare column 2 of both the files (string values) and print out the rows in `file2.csv` for the values of its column 3 that are not present in the column 3 of `file1.csv`.

I've tried using the following `awk` command:

```
awk -F'\t''NR==FNR{c[$3]++;next};c[$3] == 0' file1.csv file2.csv
```

This however just gives me all of `file2.csv`. There are only 2 extra rows in `file2.csv` that are not present in `file1.csv`.

Could someone tell me what it is I'm doing wrong?

Snippet of `file1.csv` (Columns are numbered from 0)

```
ANR     26545   CallExpression                  mutex_unlock ( & mmc_test_lock )
ANR     26546   Callee                          mutex_unlock
ANR     26547   Identifier                      mutex_unlock
ANR     26548   ArgumentList                    & mmc_test_lock
ANR     26549   Argument                        & mmc_test_lock
ANR     26550   UnaryOperationExpression        & mmc_test_lock
ANR     26551   UnaryOperator                   &
ANR     26552   Identifier                      mmc_test_lock
ANR     26553   ExpressionStatement             "__free_pages ( test -> highmem , BUFFER_ORDER )"
ANR     26554   CallExpression                  "__free_pages ( test -> highmem , BUFFER_ORDER )" 
ANR     26555   Callee                          __free_pages 
ANR     26556   Identifier                      __free_pages
ANR     26557   ArgumentList                    test -> highmem
ANR     26558   Argument                        test -> highmem 
ANR     26559   PtrMemberAccess                 test -> highmem
ANR     26560   Identifier                      test
ANR     26561   Identifier                      highmem
ANR     26562   Argument                        BUFFER_ORDER
ANR     26563   Identifier                      BUFFER_ORDER
```

Snippet of `file2.csv`

```
ANR     12910   CallExpression                  mutex_unlock ( & mmc_test_lock )
ANR     12911   Callee                          mutex_unlock
ANR     12912   Identifier                      mutex_unlock
ANR     12913   ArgumentList                    & mmc_test_lock
ANR     12914   Argument                        & mmc_test_lock
ANR     12915   UnaryOperationExpression        & mmc_test_lock
ANR     12916   UnaryOperator                   & 
ANR     12917   Identifier                      mmc_test_lock 
ANR     12918   IfStatement                     if ( test -> highmem )
ANR     12919   Condition                       test -> highmem 
ANR     12920   PtrMemberAccess                 test -> highmem
ANR     12921   Identifier                      test
ANR     12922   Identifier                      highmem
ANR     12923   ExpressionStatement             "__free_pages ( test -> highmem , BUFFER_ORDER )"
ANR     12924   CallExpression                  "__free_pages ( test -> highmem , BUFFER_ORDER )" 
ANR     12925   Callee                          __free_pages
ANR     12926   Identifier                      __free_pages
ANR     12927   ArgumentList                    test -> highmem
ANR     12928   Argument                        test -> highmem
ANR     12929   PtrMemberAccess                 test -> highmem
ANR     12930   Identifier                      test
ANR     12931   Identifier                      highmem
ANR     12932   Argument                        BUFFER_ORDER
ANR     12933   Identifier                      BUFFER_ORDER
```

Expected output:

```
ANR     12918   IfStatement     if ( test -> highmem )
ANR     12919   Condition       test -> highmem
```

Comment: Do you have to do this in `awk`? If not, take a look at `diff`.

Comment: Please post some sample data along with expected output.

Comment: None of the second column match the other file...

Comment: The columns are numbered from 0.

Comment: @JamilSaid, I'm happy to use diff if it gives me the desired output! :) I just thought awk would be more efficient.

Comment: @AnnaR No they aren't.

Comment: @123 Are they not? I'm sorry, I wasn't aware. Using c[$3] gave me a blank file, I assumed it was numbered form 0. I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your awk command to this:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR {seen[$2]; next} !($2 in seen)' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question! However, that didn't work either.

Comment: In that case you need to post sample data from 2 csv files and expected output.

Comment: 2nd column in file2 are all `12...` but in file1 you have all `26...` so of course there is no match

Comment: I apologize, another user here corrected me. I assumed the columns were numbered from 0. However, using c[$3] just gives me a blank file. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Now `PtrMemberAccess` and `Identifier` values are present in both file's 3rd column so why should those values be in output?

Comment: I seem to be making  a lot of errors today. I apologize again.

Comment: No problem. Now my above awk command is producing exact output as you've shown in question. (Make sure your input files are all tab delimited)

Comment: This works! Thank you very much! I really appreciate it!